# БД не удаляет запись, но SQL обрабатывает, работаю с JOIN-ами

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Берет `id` из таблицы `users`,  и ищет в таблице `phones_user` этот `id` в колонке  `id_users`, если совпало, то удаляет запись.

Есть такой запрос: `DELETE FROM phones_users WHERE id_user = 213` он работает.

```
 Таблица `users`
+-----+-----------------+---------------+
| id  | user_first_name | user_last_name|
+-----+-----------------+---------------+
| 213 |  Eugen          | Podlevskykh   |
+-----+-----------------+---------------+
| 214 |  Dima           | Mukhin        |
+-----+-----------------+---------------+
```

---

```
Таблица `phones_users`
  +-----+-----------+------------+
  | id  |  id_user  | phone_1    |
  +-----+-----------+------------+
  | 180 |  213      | 0993331285 |
  +-----+-----------+------------+
  | 181 |  214      | 3663223345 |
  +-----+-----------+------------+
```

---

Этот нет

```
   DELETE `users`, `phones_users` 
   FROM `users` 
   JOIN `phones_users` 
   ON users.id = phones_users.id_user 
   WHERE phones_users.id = 213
```

Запрос сделан, ошибок нет, и приходит ответ:

```
Затронуто 0 строк. (Запрос занял 0,0000 сек.)
```

Comment: Может имелось в виду `WHERE phones_users.id_user = 213` вместо фильтра по id? Ну или `WHERE users.id = 213`

Comment: В показанных исходных данных нет записи с `phones_users.id = 213`.

Comment: Спасибо, я увидел что вместо `WHERE phones_users.id = 213` надо `WHERE users.id = 213`